# How does message attachments work in Outlook REST API

Tags: outlook-restapi

this is what i'm trying to accomplish:

First i'm using the beta version of the API.

So i'm using
/api/beta/me/messages/{message_id}/replyall
and
/api/beta/me/messages/{message_id}/forward
endpoints.
The Comment of the reply/forward message is not set.
A new message is sent in the request.
This message contains the exact attachments i want for the message to have. And the message body contains the whole message text (we construct our own message history).

The result from this request is that the created reply/forward message contains the attachments that i have send AND the attachments that are part of the message i reply to/forward.

Under attachments i mean both inline files and attached files.

The message body is constructed correctly.

I also tried creating a draft and then updating the attachments for this draft using:
PATCH /api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}
for which in the documentation is said that i can specify "one or more writable message properties in the request body", but for some reason it does not work with message attachments. But i guess even if it does work with attachments, it will just add the attachments that i send and won't delete the old ones.

So is there some parameter that i can set, so i can accomplish this behavior?

I tried to make a request to https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/messages/{message_id}/createreply
and then delete the unwanted attachments from the returned draft message. The problem here is that this endpoint doesn't return the attachments. I also tried adding the $expand=attachments query, but still no attachments returned.

Comment: I got a bit lost. Did you manage to send requests to /reply, /replyall and /forward with attachments in it? I'm confused if you did it or if that's what you want to do but hasn't been able to yet.
If you've managed to do it, could you please tell me how you did? I've been trying to find an example of how to reply/forward with attachments and got nothing so far... Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, i manage to reply/forward with attachments and it works in the general case. In the beta version of the rest api you can send also a Message in the request body. 
Your request should be to https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/messages/{message_id}/reply
So if you add the attachments to this message (as you would do for /sendmail endpoint) it should work.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! :D Do you know if there's any way of doing this in the stable (non beta) versions of the API? Or someplace where I can find information about how reliable is the beta version (or what are their plans for it)? Thanks once more!

Comment: Also, regarding your attempt of deleting the attachments of the draft message, if you send a GET to https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/messages/{msg_id}/attachments/ you can see all the attachments of that message. A following DELETE to https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/messages/{msg_id}/attachments/{attachment_id} deletes that attachment from the message. Does this help you?

Comment: You almost answered your own question ;)
So with the current API version:
1. Create a draft ( Post to /createreply) that contains only the reply message body (Comment). This will return the message that you just created (apparently without the attachments). Get the id of the draft. 2. Use this to create the attachments that you want to this draft message. (Post to /messages/{message_id}/attachments) 3. Send the draft message.

Comment: I couldn't test it yet, but it makes sense! Very clever tip, haha. Thanks again, and hope you've solved your question by now :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with attachments when forward/reply/replyAll and I figured the best way of doing this, is to construct your new message with all the attachments that you want (like the way you are doing it) and then simply use the send api call, i.e., 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/sendmail' with your new message. I hope it works for you!

Comment: Great question. Here is what you need to do if you want the reply to be in the same thread: The original email has a parameter called "ConversationId", all you have to do, is to get this Id and pass it on to the reply message, i.e., your message should look something like this: var messageFinal = {
  "Message": {
     "ToRecipients": $scope.message.toRecipients, 
     "Subject": $scope.message.subject,
       "Body": {
             "ContentType": "HTML",
              "Content": $scope.message.content
         },
         "ConversationId" : $scope.message.ConversationId
        }
};